# HTML tables: how to stack columns rather than rows for mobile display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

For an html table with vertical headers, how would I stack columns rather than rows for mobile display? In other words, achieve an output that looks like this on mobile:

A1

A2

A3

B1

B2

B3

C1

C2

C3

In a normal table (horizontal headers), this mobile effect is quite easy. See example (mobile width set absurdly large to force effect on desktop):

```css
table {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
}

td {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 20000px) {
table {width:100%;}
thead {display: none;}
tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
tr td:first-child {background: #f0f0f0; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;}
tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
tbody td:before { 
    content: attr(data-th); 
    display: block;
    text-align:center;  
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Header A</th>
<th>Header B</th>
<th>Header C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>A1</td>
<td>B1</td>
<td>C1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A2</td>
<td>B2</td>
<td>C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A3</td>
<td>B3</td>
<td>C3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But for my irregular table (vertical headers), I'm utterly lost on how to achieve that same effect. See example (no attempt at the mobile effect, just the table):

```css
table {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
}

td {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class='comparison-table'>
 <tr>
  <th>Header A</th>
  <td>A1 </td>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td>A3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header B</th>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header C</th>
  <td>C1</td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td>C3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header D</th>
  <td>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can do for the second table, roughly the same thing I did for the first table?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) instead of tables.

Comment: Edit: I screwed this whole question up. Desired output is "A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2 . . ."  You all were great at providing solutions to a different problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: Edit: I'm marking this as answered, since there is a solution to the question I actually asked, and that question might be useful for someone else. I'll resubmit a similar question with my actual intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}

td {
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class='comparison-table'>
 <tr>
  <th>Header A</th>
  <td>A1 </td>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td>A3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header B</th>
  <td>B1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>B3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header C</th>
  <td>C1</td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td>C3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Header D</th>
  <td>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Added a `display: block` on table cells.

Comment: A more complicated version of this works for the more complicated tables I'm working with (previous css interferes with the simple solution). But if I go through and add a class to each member of a column (e.g., class = "column-2"), and then apply "display:block" to each column class in the @media settings, this works. I don't expect you to do all my work for me, so this answer is plenty. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding display: table-row; rather than block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but if you switch to `display: table` instead of an actual `<table>` in your HTML for desktop, you could write up media queries to make the display on mobile not even be a table (for example you could just set them to be block divs on mobile).

Comment: Then he doesn't have a data table and the document structure is now different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use divs instead of table, like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .block {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 24.9%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .header.block {
        clear: both;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .block {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .header.block {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .block {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

and html it look like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="header block">A - header block</div>
    <div class="block">A1<br>a1</div>
    <div class="block">A2</div>
    <div class="block">A3</div>
    <div class="header block">B - header block</div>
    <div class="block">B1</div>
    <div class="block">B2<br>b2</div>
    <div class="block">B3</div>
    <div class="header block">C - header block</div>
    <div class="block">C1</div>
    <div class="block">C2</div>
    <div class="block">C3<br>c3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then he doesn't have a table and tables are for data. The HTML structure will be totally different. This is not the answer he is looking for.